# Start Daemons from Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

Is it possible to start up a daemon from java. Specifically, I am trying to use MongoDB in java however I want my application to start up the mongod daemon if it not already running. I seem to be able to start it ok, exitcode is 0. However it always exits immediately. Is it possible to force it to stay running, then quit it with proc.destroy()?

`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./bin/mongod","--dbpath data/db");
Process proc = pb.start();`

If i set a breakpoint after i start the process the hasExisted boolean is always true, the exit code is 0 and I cannot connect to.

Also this is on OS X 10.5, I know ProcessBuilder is finicky across OS

Comment: `./mongod --dbpath data/db` doesn't start mongodb in the daemon mode. you have to use `./mongod --fork --dbpath data/db --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend` for starting it as a daemon. If not started as daemon, you have to handle the stdin/stdout/stderr yourself for a process started with `ProcessBuilder.start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command and path are probably not handled properly.
Here is what needs to be done in pseudo java (groovy) to run mongodb after a fresh install with [brew](https://brew.sh/)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(["/usr/local/bin/mongod","run", "--config", "/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.0.1-x86_64/mongod.conf"]); 

Process process = pb.start()

InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
}
    

int exitValue = process.waitFor()
print exitValue
```

You can type the above directly in a groovy console.